# AS3 Save SWF to iOS device and then load it back into a MovieClip

Tags: ios, actionscript-3, file-io, flash

I have an iOS app that's using AS3 and AIR.  I have external swfs downloading from a server and playing properly--all of this works perfectly fine.

I don't want the user to have to download these swfs every time they launch the app, though, so after the swf is downloaded the first time I want to save it to disk.  That way I can load it from the local copy when I need it in the future, instead of downloading it again.  I found this example online for saving files in AS3:

```
var file:File = File.applicationStorageDirectory.resolvePath("Swfs/" + "mySwfName" + ".swf");
var wr:File = new File(file.nativePath);
var stream:FileStream = new FileStream();
stream.open(wr, FileMode.WRITE);
stream.writeBytes(SWF_FILE_GOES_HERE, 0, SWF_FILE_DATA_LENGTH_GOES_HERE);
stream.close();
```

The problem is in the `writeBytes` line.  The sample I found was for saving images to disk, and that line read like this:

```
stream.writeBytes(imageData, 0, imageData.length);
```

But I need to do this for a swf, not an image, and I'm not sure how to get the requisite data from my swf file.  I've searched online for saving swf files, getting data from swf files, etc...  But I haven't found anything.  I need to get the swf's data and data length (I'm assuming this is a number of bytes?).  Has anyone solved this problem before, or have a resource they can point me in the direction of?

---

UPDATE: Based on @LondonDrugs_MediaServices' comments, I figured out the `writeBytes` line:

```
stream.writeBytes(mySwf.loaderInfo.bytes, 0, mySwf.loaderInfo.bytesTotal);
```

This seems to work, in as much as it compiles and runs without errors.  But when I try to grab the file and put it back into a movie clip, I get this error:

```
Error #2044: Unhandled IOErrorEvent:. text=Error #2035: URL Not Found.
```

Which implies that the file was not, in fact, saved correctly.  When I print the file locations, however, they seem to be right!  When I save the file to the applicationStorageDirectory:

```
/Users/MyName/Library/Preferences/com.appdir/Local Store/Swfs/mySwName.swf
```

And the filename when I try and load it out of storage and into a movie clip:

```
/Users/MyName/Library/Preferences/com.appdir/Local Store/Swfs/mySwName.swf
```

This is the code I'm using to try and load it back into a movie clip:

```
var videoFileName:String = "Swfs/" + ENVAR.currentVideoSelected + ".swf";
var videoFilePath:File = File.applicationStorageDirectory.resolvePath(videoFileName);   
var inFileStream:FileStream = new FileStream(); 
trace("[Loading] filepath: ", videoFilePath.nativePath);
inFileStream.open(videoFilePath, FileMode.READ); 
var fileContents:String = inFileStream.readUTFBytes(inFileStream.bytesAvailable);   
inFileStream.close(); 

var req:URLRequest = new URLRequest(videoFilePath.nativePath);
var mLoader:Loader = new Loader();
mLoader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, onVideoLoadComplete);
mLoader.load(req);
```

And my `onVideoLoadComplete` function contains these lines:

```
var myMC:MovieClip = e.target.content as MovieClip;
addChild(myMC);
```

But I'm getting that error 2044 and it doesn't think the file exists.  Can anyone spot the problem?  Thanks!

Comment: http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/LoaderInfo.html#bytes

Comment: so in theory I think you should be able to use the loaderInfo.bytes property of your swf to save them back out again with stream.writeBytes, never tried it though which is why I'm not doing this as an answer.

Comment: If you intend to submit this app to the App Store, I think it will be rejected because it loads and runs external code (the swf).

Comment: If the swf is just content like a movie playing or assets and no code it should be fine.

Comment: @LondonDrugs_MediaServices Thanks for the info!  I'll give it a try.  BarisUsakli Yes, this is the case.  It's just a movie :)

Comment: @LondonDrugs_MediaServices Thanks again for your help.  Please see my update; I think I'm saving it properly now, but I can't figure out how to use `writeBytes` to pull it back out and into a MovieClip.  If you can point me in the right direction you'd have my undying gratitude (and an accept if you posted this as the answer!)

Comment: Wouldn't you just get it the same way you get it remotely but use the local path instead? Like with a loader.  I don't have much experience with loading files on iOS (eg what apple blocks and doesn't allow).

Comment: @LondonDrugs_MediaServices Haha, I just updated the question again right as you posted that :)  I thought of that and tried it, but it gives me a URL not found error, implying the file wasn't actually saved properly in the first place...

Comment: @LondonDrugs_MediaServices `videoFilePath.exists` returns true. What I'm trying now is to convert a byte array to a movieclip--I realized that I'd been using `readUTFBytes` when I really wanted `readBytes`.  But the docs seem contradictory--they say `Reads the number of data bytes, specified by the length parameter, from the file stream, byte stream, or byte array.` But when I try `var swfBytes:ByteArray = inFileStream.readBytes(inFileStream);` it says I need to pass a ByteArray object to `readBytes`. If I already have the byte array what's the point in reading it? Don't get this fcn's usage.

Comment: @LondonDrugs_MediaServices Once I get the byte array I think I can use a loader like this `mLoader.loadBytes(swfBytes, loaderContext);` to get a movieclip from the byteArray, but I'm having trouble getting the byteArray in the first place.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/16116/discussion-between-londondrugs-mediaservices-and-wendikidd)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get the raw bytes of a loaded swf file by using it's  `loaderInfo.bytes` parameter.  So for you example you could do this:

```
var file:File = File.applicationStorageDirectory.resolvePath("Swfs/" + key + ".swf"); 
var wr:File = new File(file.nativePath); 
var stream:FileStream = new FileStream(); 
stream.open(wr, FileMode.WRITE); 
stream.writeBytes(mySwf.loaderInfo.bytes, 0, mySwf.loaderInfo.bytesTotal); 
stream.close();
```

Then to pull it back out into a MovieClip:

```
var videoFileName:String = "Swfs/" + ENVAR.currentVideoSelected + ".swf";
var videoFilePath:File = File.applicationStorageDirectory.resolvePath(videoFileName); 
var inFileStream:FileStream = new FileStream(); 
inFileStream.open(videoFilePath, FileMode.READ); 
var swfBytes:ByteArray = new ByteArray();
inFileStream.readBytes(swfBytes);
inFileStream.close(); 

var mLoader:Loader = new Loader();
var loaderContext:LoaderContext = new LoaderContext(false, ApplicationDomain.currentDomain);
loaderContext.allowCodeImport = true;
mLoader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, onVideoLoadComplete);
mLoader.loadBytes(swfBytes, loaderContext);
```